# Loop through each object of an array and append each object from second array to the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects. I need to loop through the first array and append each object of the second array to each object of the first array.

First array:

```
const productsArray = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1'},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2'}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3'}
];
```

Second Array:

```
const quantitiesArray = [
  {Quantity: 100},
  {Quantity: 300}, 
  {Quantity: 600}
];
```

Desired Outcome:

```
const newProductsArray = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1', Quantity: 100},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2', Quantity: 300}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3', Quantity: 600}
]
```

There will always be the same amount of objects in each array.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Do you know about [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)?

Comment: Please share what research or attempts you have already done.
Solution: There are multiple ways this can be achieved but hint for one of the possible solutions: Just run a simple **for** loop on one of your arrays and copy items at given index from both arrays into one of your arrays. Use something like this to set your value at given index `{ ...productsArray[i], ...quantitiesArray[i] };` 

P.S.: Please check out JavaScript `Spread syntax (...)` to understand more about `...object` usage. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const productsArray = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1'},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2'}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3'}
], quantitiesArray = [
  {Quantity: 100},
  {Quantity: 300}, 
  {Quantity: 600}
];

const res=quantitiesArray.map((q,i)=>(
 {...productsArray[i],...q}
))

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should point you in the right direction. A loop plus Object.assign() I believe is what you're looking for.

```js
const productsArray = [{
    Name: 'product1',
    SKU: 'sku1'
  },
  {
    Name: 'product2',
    SKU: 'sku2'
  },
  {
    Name: 'product3',
    SKU: 'sku3'
  }
];

const quantitiesArray = [{
    Quantity: 100
  },
  {
    Quantity: 300
  },
  {
    Quantity: 600
  }
];

function appendArray() {
  let assignedArray;
  for (let i = 0; i < productsArray.length; i++) {
    assignedArray = Object.assign(productsArray[i], quantitiesArray[i])
  }
  return assignedArray;
}

console.log(appendArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const productsArray = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1'},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2'}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3'}
];

const quantitiesArray  = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1', Quantity: 100},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2', Quantity: 300}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3', Quantity: 600}
];

const newProductsArray = [];

productsArray.forEach((item,index) => {
    newProductsArray.push({...item,...quantitiesArray[index]});
});

console.log(newProductsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is a completely new array, you can use `Array#map` - which creates a new array, and the spread operator as follows:

```js
const productsArray = [
  {Name: 'product1', SKU: 'sku1'},
  {Name: 'product2', SKU: 'sku2'}, 
  {Name: 'product3', SKU: 'sku3'}
];

const quantitiesArray = [
  {Quantity: 100},
  {Quantity: 300}, 
  {Quantity: 600}
];

const newProductsArray = productsArray.map(
    (prodArr,i) => ({...prodArr, ...quantitiesArray[i]})
)

console.log( newProductsArray );
```